# Managing GCP Composer Kubernetes cluster using Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-composer

I've created a GCP Composer environment [using Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/composer_environment):

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.5.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  credentials = file("my_key.json")
  project = "my_project_id"
  region  = "us-east1"
  zone    = "us-east1-b"
}

resource "google_composer_environment" "my_composer_id" {
  name   = "my_composer_name"
  region = "us-east1"
  config {
    node_count = 3
    node_config {
      zone         = "us-east1-b"
      machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
    }
  }
}
```

Composer also automatically creates a Kubernetes Engine cluster. Such cluster has a single node pool called *default-pool*. **I'd like to [create a new node pool](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_node_pool) inside the cluster created by Composer**. Something like this:

```
resource "google_container_node_pool" "my_node_pool_id" {
  name       = "my_node_pool_name"
  location   = "us-east1"
  cluster    = ????
  node_count = 0
  node_config {
    preemptible  = true
    machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
  }
  autoscaling  {
    min_node_count = 0
    max_node_count = 3
  }
}
```

However, as I didn't create the cluster in the Terraform file (as it was automatically created by Composer), I don't have the reference to it.

Comment: What if you followed this [doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_node_pool) to added a new node pool. give a try with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cluster name can be accessed via the key [`gke_cluster` available in the `config` section](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/composer_environment#config.0.gke_cluster) of your Cloud Composer environment :

```
resource "google_container_node_pool" "my_node_pool_id" {
  name       = "my_node_pool_name"
  location   = "us-east1-b"

  cluster    = element(
      split("/",
        lookup(
          google_composer_environment.my_composer_id.config[0],
          "gke_cluster"
        )
      ),
      5
    )

  // ...
}
```

The 5th element corresponds to the name of the GKE cluster.

Comment: I have the following in my terraform.tfstate file:
"gke_cluster": "projects/my_project_name/zones/us-east1-b/clusters/my_cluster_name", So instead of 11 it should be 5, right?

Comment: Hm, I think you should try 5. Let me know if that worked !

Comment: When I run "terraform apply", I'm getting the error 404: Not Found: projects/my_project_name/locations/us-east1/clusters/my_cluster_name., notFound. And even if I hardcode my cluster name as in: cluster = my_cluster_name. I still get the same error message.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I was using location = "us-east1" in my node pool definition, and I think I should be using "us-east1-b" instead. I got that solution here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/5229
Not sure if it's going to work, the node pool is still being created.

Comment: @MatheusSchaly Glad it worked ! Finally, did you use index 11 or 5 (so I can update my answer) ?

Comment: I used 5 and location = "us-east1-b". Other than that, it's the same thing as in your code.